# Не работает @media правило, когда в DevTool crome выбран device type Desktop, когда выбираю mobile работает

Tags: media

Не могу понять делаю адаптацию сайта в HTML есть тег:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

В файле _media.scss прописываю правило:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .header {
        width: 1200px;
    }
}
```

Когда в DevTool crome выбран device type Desktop медиа правило не работает, когда выбираю mobile работает

Answer (score -1):

идентичная проблема. Поделитесь решением.
Head:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
```

медазапрос:

```
@media screen and (min-height: 768px) and (min-width: 1000px) and (orientation: landscape) {}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Обратите внимание, вы дали ответ. На ответ вам никто не ответит. [Задайте новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) и сошлитесь на текуший, если есть взаимосвязь. Это сообщение, пожалуйста, удалите.